# Mean, Mode, Median of a histogram?

Tags: mean, median, histogram, mode

Based on my understandings, I would say for the below histogram that the mode is zero, the mean is between 0 & 1 and the median is 1. I'm I right?

[image: Histogram]

Comment: It's not a histogram, it's a bar plot. Anyway, I would say all except mean are 0.

Answer (score 1):

- As noticed in the comment, this is a bar plot. Histogram would pack the values into bins. For discrete data we don't use histograms in general, maybe unless there is a huge  number of categories what would make the bar plot less unreadable.
- Mode is the most frequent value, so the highest bar.
- Mean would be the sum of $x$-axis values multiplied by their frequencies, i.e. $y$-axis, i.e. ${\sum_i x_i y_i} \Big/ {\sum_i y_i}$. You could calculate it from the plot with some degree of precision after reading the heights from $y$-axis.
- Median is the value "in the middle" if you sorted the values. It would be 1 if after stacking the bars things on right would be slightly higher than things on left. The plots have $y$-axis on the logarithmic scale, so again, you would need to read the height of the bars to figure out if $y_0 \approx y_1 + y_2 + y_3$, but you can visually verify that this is not the case, so the median is also zero.

Comment: It would be helpful, I suspect, to indicate that the mean will be approximately $0.001.$ Your remarks about "measure the height of the bars" are puzzling, considering their values are clearly marked on the vertical axis (on a *logarithmic* scale).

Comment: @whuber I meant that you'd need to use a ruler to make more precise reading of the values. Nonetheless, I improved the wording.